# What is this good for - determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

Ok, Using RRef and the identity matrix I can find the inverse matrix and the solution vector with out (directly) finding the determinant of a square matrix. But I have to believe, if this was the only thing determinants were good for ( finding inverses and solving systems of equations) they might be abandoned as curiosities. So what what other avenues of math do determinants open up?  Really, what is a determinant good for?

Answer (score 2):

One really useful application about determinants I like is that if it is non-zero, you know that your equations are linearly independent, which is useful once you start studying span, bases, etc...

The geometric interpretation of the determinant is the area of the parallelogram, and the absolute value of the determinant of real vectors is equal to the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by those vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is what differentiates the groups $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$, that is it tells if a rotation is a "pure" rotation, or if it contains a reflection as well.